# Creating object property with array values from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a new table from reading the DOM by having trouble with the object creation. Right now, I'm able to get it as `{100: 4}` varied for each row. I'm thinking the best way to get my desired result is to make an object that looks like such for each ID `{ID: [loc, value, bax]}` Should look like such based upon my current table. The location will be always be the same for each ID depending on the first location selected so for this instance, 100 will always be USA

### Desired

### ID | Location | Value | BAX

100 | USA | 4 | 55

My Current HTML and JS

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Bax</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name ="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name ="location" value="USA"></td>
    <td><input name="initValue" value='1'></td>
    <td><input name="bax" value='22'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name ="itinValue" value="300"></td>
    <td><input name ="location" value="CAN"></td>
    <td><input name="initValue" value='2'></td>
    <td><input name="bax" value='11'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name ="itinValue" value="100"></td>
    <td><input name ="location" value="USA"></td>
    <td><input name="initValue" value='3'></td>
    <td><input name="bax" value='33'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name ="itinValue" value="200"></td>
    <td><input name ="location" value="MEX"></td>
    <td><input name="initValue" value='4'></td>
    <td><input name="bax" value='44'></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-two">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Bax</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
const itin = document.querySelectorAll('[name="itinValue"]');

var values = {};
var i  = 1;

itin.forEach((item, i) => {
  var idValue = item.value;
  var next = document.getElementsByName('initValue')[i].value;
  if (values.hasOwnProperty(idValue)) {
    values[idValue] = values[idValue] += parseInt(next);
  } else {
    values[idValue] = parseInt(next);
  }
  i++;
});


var table_two = document.querySelector('.table-two tbody');

for (var prop in values) {
  var val = values[prop];
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td1 = document.createElement('td');
  var td2 = document.createElement('td');
  td1.innerHTML = prop;
  td2.innerHTML = val;
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  table_two.appendChild(tr);
}
```

and thats printing out the ID and Values correctly. I was thinking of along the lines of doing the same thing for BAX total by doing the same thing as value total and giving them array spots

```
  var bax = document.getElementsByName('bax')[i].value;
  if (values.hasOwnProperty(idValue)) {
    values[idValue] = [values[idValue] += parseInt(next), values[idValue] += parseInt(bax)];
  } else {
    values[idValue] = [parseInt(next), parseInt(bax)];
  }
```

I know thats sloppy by just to give an idea of what I was thinking/trying to do. Heres a link to a quick fiddle of where im at
https://jsfiddle.net/f4ha7xe6/52/

Answer (score 0):

Was at this for awhile, finally got to a solution if anyone was interested

https://jsfiddle.net/f4ha7xe6/127/

```
code
```